# Append or add a class to a div in a nested repeater with a dynamically assigned ID?

Tags: c#, asp.net, inline, code-behind

I have this repeater within another repeater.

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rpDB_item" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="rpDB_item_ItemDataBound">
   <ItemTemplate>
        <div class="row anj" id="ncollapse<%# ((((RepeaterItem)Container.Parent.Parent).ItemIndex)) %>" >
        ...
        </div>                                              
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

What I would like to do is append to the class of the rows with `id=ncollapse(x)` with `.collapsed`.  There will potentially be several divs with and `id=ncollapse4`, for example.   How would I append the the class of those divs with a `.collapsed` class from code-behind (C#)? Or would this be better the set the class inline on the aspx page?  I would prefer to use a switch as the defining statement as there are a few options that the `sStatus` could be.

I have tried
`HtmlGenericControl nc = (HtmlGenericControl)(e.Item.FindControl("ncollapse"+((((RepeaterItem)e.Item.Parent.Parent).ItemIndex).ToString())));`

then setting the 
`nc.Attributes["class"] = "collapsed"` 
in code behind but get a null reference on `nc` (it appears to always be null); as well as,

```
<div class="row anj <%# switch (DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"sStatus").ToString())
{ case "OFFLINE": case "RECOVERY_PENDING": case "UNKNOWN":
        Response.Write("collapsed");
        break;
  default:
        Response.Write("");
        break;
 };%> id="<%# (DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"sStatus").ToString() == "OFFLINE" ? "n" : "ncollapse"+((((RepeaterItem)Container.Parent.Parent).ItemIndex).ToString())) %>">
```

This is giving me an error with `switch`.  Not sure where I am going worng or where to turn to next.  thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is probably a way to get your aspx syntax right, but is it worth it? It is hardly readable. I would suggest to move this logic to code behind and then call it from markup. Easy to write, easy to read, easy to manage.

Code behind of the page:

```
protected string getRowCollapsedClass(String sStatus)
{
    switch (sStatus)
    {
        case "OFFLINE":
        case "RECOVERY_PENDING":
        case "UNKNOWN":
            return "collapsed";
        default:
            return String.Empty;
    }
}
```

And then markup becomes really simple:

```
<div class='row anj <%# getRowCollapsedClass(Eval("sStatus").ToString()) %>'
```

Likewise for the id value. Just remember to pass index as a second parameter.

Comment: That might be my best option.  I look into that.  However with that the break is not necessary as the return clause will supersede the break and break will be unused or needed.

Comment: Thnaks for reminding me to KISS - Keep It Simple Solution.  It works perfectly.  Now to get the rest of the accordion and toggle class working